# In ExtractHogFeatures Matlab a line that I can't understand

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

In matlab 2014b in vision toolbox, in extractHOGFeatures.m there's a line that says

```
hog = visionExtractHOGFeatures(gMag, gDir, gaussianWeights, params, weights);
```

I've looked for ***visionExtractHOGFeatures*** everywhere in matlab it seems to be a function, but I can't find anything about it. extractHOGFeatures.m uses it, it seems to be important for the algorithm and I want to fully understand the code. What can it be? How can I find what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an internal function.  Unfortunately, you cannot see the source, because it is compiled code.

Comment: Even so in matlab  generally some information on internal functions is given. I guess they missed this one. I can't vote up so thanks.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to find out? The implementation is based on the Dalal and Triggs paper cited in the documentation.

Comment: I have the paper, and I'm trying to understand the code concurrently. I guess I'll complete the missing part myself in my code. Thanx.

Comment: you can see the source code, as is a opencv dll:  https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp